# I would like to use an array from an inventory form in another form without having the inventory form load is that possible?

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio-2015, separation-of-concerns

I have labels that I have added to an array and I need to use that array to verify the values in the labels.

I wont be opening the inventory form to do so, I will be ordering from an order form which is a different form.

In the inventory form I have created an int array that holds the contents of the label. in the order form i have tried to use

```
int[] inventory = Form2.items[]
```

to try and send it to an array in the order form so i can manipulate it but it doesn't work.

Is there a  way i can use that array in inventory in my order form without loading the inventory form?

The first top part of my form for the inventory list looks like this. This is the form that I am trying to send the inventory list from. I would like to be able to use the inventory list without opening up the inventory form.

form2:
        `public form2 (  )
        {
            InitializeComponent();

```
            ArrayList foodItems = new ArrayList();

        foodItems .Add( flatBreadLabel );
        foodItems .Add( MultigrainLabel );
        foodItems .Add( pitaLabel );
        foodItems .Add( ryeLabel );
        foodItems .Add( whiteLabel );
```

}
}`

and the order form, the form that I am trying to recieve the array list from is:

`public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int [] inventory = new int [36];

```
    public Form1 (ArrayList[] foodItem)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        inventory = foodItem();
    }
    }`
```

Comment: you may have to look at separating  the UI logic from the business logic to make things/objects more easily sharable/reusable

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]

Comment: If you need to access the array without creating an instance of Form2, then the array doesn't belong in Form2.

Comment: I need to do both, use the array in the form and also use the array in another form without opening the inventory form. Sometimes ill need to change the values in the inventory form and outside of it,.

Comment: Singleton Pattern May be?

Comment: i figured it out. thanks